# Firebase notification admin.messaging() is not a function - Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Here is my code

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./google-services.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

module.exports.admin = admin
```

My API file code

```
const admin = require('../firebaseConfig')

async function sendFireBaseNotification(registrationToken , message  ){

  const options =  notification_options

  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message, options)
  .then( response => {

    console.log("Notification sent successfully"+response)
    
  })
  .catch( error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

my firebase version "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1"
I am getting error 'TypeError: admin.messaging is not a function'
I am looking for the solutions , please help.

Answer (score 0):

Version [5.13.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/releases/tag/v5.13.1) of the Firebase Admin SDK that you're using is from July 2018 (!). I recommend upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: I upgraded to '"firebase-admin": "^11.0.1"' still I am facing same issue

Comment: Please update your question to contain the [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on that updated information.